# Where is the error I am missing?

Tags: excel, date-difference, vba

This Sub will not calculate correctly if the date of birth has not been hit yet in the current year.  If the DOB is 12/31/1950 it will calculate the DOB as 56, but the person is really 55 until 12/31.  Is there an update I can add to accommodate for this.

```
Sub EE_DatedIf_ButtonC_()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow1 As Long
    Dim yrDiff As Long
    Dim d1 As Date
    Dim d2 As Date

    Set wb1 = Workbooks("macro all client v.01.xlsm")

    LastRow1 = wb1.Sheets("Carrier").range("F:F").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For i = 10 To LastRow1

        d1 = wb1.Sheets("Carrier").Cells(8, 1)

        d2 = wb1.Sheets("Carrier").Cells(i, 24)

        yrDiff = DateDiff("yyyy", d2, d1)

        wb1.Sheets("Carrier").Cells(i, 3) = yrDiff

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if  you took the number of month difference, divide that number by 12 and truncate

```
yrDiff = CInt(DateDiff("m", d2, d1) / 12)
```

or even more accurately, do the same with hours

```
yrDiff = CInt(DateDiff("h", d2, d1) / 8766)
```

**UPDATE** `CInt` will round, not truncate. Use this function here

```
Public Function Trunc(ByVal value As Double, ByVal num As Integer) As Double
    Trunc = Int(value * (10 ^ num)) / (10 ^ num)
End Function
```

And call it like so

```
yrDiff = Trunc(DateDiff("h", d2, d1) / 8766, 0)
```

Comment: @TTT I'll include that in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Nice leap year adjustment. :)

Comment: I have added this update to the Sub, but the age is still not calculating correctly.  It says the age from 4/18/1991 to 01/01/2016 is 25, but I expected it to be 24.

Comment: yrDiff = CInt(DateDiff("d", d2, d1) / 365)
    
    wb1.Sheets("Carrier").Cells(i, 3) = yrDiff
    
    Next i

Comment: Apparently `CInt` can round, not truncate. I found a handy truncate function [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347704/truncating-double-with-vba-in-excel) that works. I am updating my answer to use it.

Comment: That was purely amazing.  Thank you so much for sharing.  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: My pleasure. Happy future coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you compare the same month/day to determine if that date has passed, you will get a True or a False. In VBA True is -1 and False is 0, so you can simply add (by subtracting) when the date is already passed

```
Sub test()

    Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date
    Dim yrDiff As Long

    d2 = #5/31/1950#
    d1 = #6/30/2016#

    yrDiff = Year(d1) - Year(d2) + CLng(d1 < DateSerial(Year(d1), Month(d2), Day(d2)))
    Debug.Print yrDiff

    d2 = #7/31/1950#

    yrDiff = Year(d1) - Year(d2) + CLng(d1 < DateSerial(Year(d1), Month(d2), Day(d2)))
    Debug.Print yrDiff

End Sub
```