# How to compare numbers up to certain number of decimals in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below that compares values from two different worksheets in the same workbook, but I only need the comparison up to 2 decimal places, i.e. 123.45 instead of 123.4568786. Is there a way to specify the number of decimal values for comparison?

```
difference = 0
For col = 1 To maxcol
For row = 1 To maxrow
    colval1 = ""
    colcal2 = ""
    colval1 = Ws1.Cells(row, col)
    colval2 = Ws2.Cells(row, col)
        If colval1 <> colval2 Then
            difference = difference + 1
            Cells(row, col) = colval1 & "<>" & colval2
        End If
Next row
Next col
```

This is the output of the code:

[image]

EDIT:I declared `colval1` and `colval2` as Double, but I am still getting 'Type Mismatch' but with this line `colval1 = Ws1.Cells(row, col)`

```
difference = 0
For col = 1 To maxcol
For row = 1 To maxrow
    colval1 = 0
    colcal2 = 0
    colval1 = Ws1.Cells(row, col)
    colval2 = Ws2.Cells(row, col)
        If WorksheetFunction.Round(colval1, 2) <> WorksheetFunction.Round(colval2, 2) Then
            difference = difference + 1
            Cells(row, col) = colval1 & "<>" & colval2
        End If
Next row
Next col
```

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.Round` the numbers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truncating Double with VBA in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347704/truncating-double-with-vba-in-excel)

Comment: ^^^^^^^`If WorksheetFunction.Round(colval1 ,2)<> WorksheetFunction.Round(colval2,2) Then`

Comment: ```WorksheetFunction.Round``` would produce 123.46 instead of 123.45 if that matters in your case.

Comment: @ScottCraner sorry still fairly new with VBA...where would I place your suggested edit?

Comment: in place of your current if line

Comment: Note that as @Warcupine mentioned, rounding might not give you the right results... for example `123.451` and `123.449` would be equal after rounding to two decimals. If that's not the behavior you want, then `Format$` should work.

Comment: @ScottCraner @BigBen thank you for your suggestions. I am getting an error with the new 'If' statement and I'm not sure where to put the `Format$` in the code

Comment: make sure your `colval1` and `colval2` are declared as doubles and change the `colval1 = ""` and `colval2 = ""` to `colval1 = 0` and `colval2 = 0` respectively.

Comment: If you are getting a type mismatch on ```colval1 = Ws1.Cells(row, col)``` and ```colval1``` is a double then whatever is in that cell is not a valid number. Do you have headers? start at row 2 if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VBA's round function which returns the rounded number based on the specified number of decimal places

```
    If Round(colval1, 2) <> Round(colval2, 2) Then
        difference = difference + 1
        Cells(Row, col) = Round(colval1, 2) & "<>" & Round(colval2, 2)
    End If
```

or

```
    colval1 = Round(Ws1.Cells(Row, col), 2)
    colval2 = Round(Ws2.Cells(Row, col), 2)
    If colval1 <> colval2 Then
        difference = difference + 1
        Cells(Row, col) = colval1 & "<>" & colval2
    End If
```

regarding the right annotation of @BigBen, we can define a small function that returns the desired value without rounding

```
Public Function Round2(Num As Variant, Decimals As Variant) As Variant
    
        Round2 = IIf(IsNumeric(Num) And IsNumeric(Decimals), Int(Num * 10 ^ Decimals) / 10 ^ Decimals, CVErr(xlErrValue))
    
End Function
```

Comment: `Round` is banker's rounding, important note.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But I am getting a 'Type Mismatch'...please see the edit for clarification.

Comment: Try with:    colval1 = CDbl(Ws1.Cells(Row, col))

Answer (score 0):

There is a way: *Round down*

First, dim the variables as Currency to avoid bit errors when comparing:

```vb
Dim colval1 As Currency
Dim colcal2 As Currency
```

Then compare the rounded down values:

```vb
If Int(colval1 * 100) / 100 <> Int(colval2 * 100) / 100 Then
```

For extended rounding methods, see my project [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round), which also includes a generic *RoundDown* function. An Excel demo in also included.

Answer (score -1):

I would truncate the value to two decimal places as following and not deal with any rounding functions.

```
Dim decimalPlaces As Long: decimalPlaces = 2
Dim scale As Long: scale = 10 ^ decimalPlaces
dim trunc as Long

For col = 1 To maxcol
For row = 1 To maxrow
    colval1 = 0
    colcal2 = 0
    colval1 = Ws1.Cells(row, col) 
    colval2 = Ws2.Cells(row, col)
    trunc = Fix(colval1 * lScale) / lScale
    if (trunc <> colval2)
            difference = difference + 1
            Cells(row, col) = colval1 & "<>" & colval2
        End If
Next row
Next col
```