# Significant figure formula in VBA gives inconsistent results in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have to perform calculations in Excel with uncertainties, but in order for them to be exact, they must be rounded to one significant figure. I found the following formula online that works directly in Excel:

```
=ROUND(number,digits-(1+INT(LOG10(ABS(number)))))
```

However, this is quite cumbersome, and I'd like to create a formula that just takes 2 arguments.

I found how to do so but while testing my formula, I've noticed that it does not give me consistent results. At first, it seemed to be off by one value. For instance, when I put `=SIGFIGS(3.1415, 2)` it output `3`, so I removed the minus 1 from the above equation.

Here is what I wrote in VBA:

```
Public Function sigfig(number As Single, sigfigs As Integer) As Single
    sigfig = Round(number, sigfigs - Int(Log(Abs(number)))))
End Function
```

Now, sometimes I get the right amount of significant figures, sometimes I get too many or too little. And for large values I get a `#VALUE` error.

I don't understand what the error in my code is, I thought it was that `Int()` didn't behave as it did in Excel, but it seems to, so I have no idea of the problem

Comment: With your UDF on my machine `=SIGFIGS(3.1415, 2) => 3.099999905`  Also, what specific numbers result in `#VALUE!`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truncating Double with VBA in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347704/truncating-double-with-vba-in-excel)

Comment: try this formula `= Fix(number * (10 ^ digits)) / (digits ^ b)`

Comment: My mistake was in using the `Log()` function. I thought it was a base 10 log but it actually is the natural log. Replacing with `Log(Abs(number))/Log(10)` worked. However, I still get a `#VALUE!` error when I want less sig figs than non-decimal values in the number, for instance: `sigfig(123.456, 2)`, which is normal, but I'll look for a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my function *RoundSignificantCur* found here: [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round).

```vb
' Common constants.
'
' Base values.
Public Const Base2      As Double = 2
Public Const Base10     As Double = 10


' Rounds Value to have significant figures as specified with parameter Digits.
'
' Performs no rounding if Digits is zero.
' Rounds to integer if NoDecimals is True.
'
' Rounds correctly Value until max/min value of currency type multiplied with 10
' raised to the power of (the number of digits of the index of Value) minus Digits.
' This equals roughly +/-922 * 10 ^ 12 for any Value of Digits.
'
' Uses CDec() to prevent bit errors of reals.
'
' For rounding of values reaching the boundaries of type Currency, use the
' function RoundSignificantDec.
'
' Requires:
'   Function Log10.
'
' 2018-02-09. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RoundSignificantCur( _
    ByVal Value As Currency, _
    ByVal Digits As Integer, _
    Optional ByVal NoDecimals As Boolean, _
    Optional ByVal MidwayRoundingToEven As Boolean) _
    As Variant
    
    Dim Exponent    As Double
    Dim Scaling     As Double
    Dim Half        As Variant
    Dim ScaledValue As Variant
    Dim ReturnValue As Currency
    
    ' Only round if Value is numeric and result can be different from zero.
    If Not IsNumeric(Value) Then
        ' Nothing to do.
        ReturnValue = Null
    ElseIf (Value = 0 Or Digits <= 0) Then
        ' Nothing to round.
        ' Return Value as is.
        ReturnValue = Value
    Else
        ' Calculate scaling factor.
        Exponent = Int(Log10(Abs(Value))) + 1 - Digits
        If NoDecimals = True Then
            ' No decimals.
            If Exponent < 0 Then
                Exponent = 0
            End If
        End If
        Scaling = Base10 ^ Exponent
        
        If Scaling = 0 Then
            ' A very large value for Digits has minimized scaling.
            ' Return Value as is.
            ReturnValue = Value
        Else
            ' Very large values for Digits can cause an out-of-range error when dividing.
            On Error Resume Next
            ScaledValue = CDec(Value) / Scaling
            If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                ' Return value as is.
                ReturnValue = Value
            Else
                ' Perform rounding.
                If MidwayRoundingToEven = False Then
                    ' Round away from zero.
                    Half = CDec(Sgn(Value) / 2)
                    ReturnValue = CCur(Fix(ScaledValue + Half) * Scaling)
                Else
                    ' Round to even.
                    ReturnValue = CCur(Round(ScaledValue) * Scaling)
                End If
                If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                    ' Rounding failed because values are near one of the boundaries of type Currency.
                    ' Return value as is.
                    ReturnValue = Value
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
  
    RoundSignificantCur = ReturnValue

End Function


' Returns Log 10 of Value.
'
' 2018-02-09. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function Log10( _
    ByVal Value As Double) _
    As Double

    ' No error handling as this should be handled
    ' outside this function.
    '
    ' Example:
    '
    '     If MyValue > 0 then
    '         LogMyValue = Log10(MyValue)
    '     Else
    '         ' Do something else ...
    '     End If
    
    Log10 = Log(Value) / Log(Base10)

End Function
```

Comment: Are you sure that this function doesn't need have any other requirements? I've copied and pasted it (Log10 also) and I get a `#VALUE!` error when I try with `(123.456, 4)` as arguments or any other value for that matter...

Comment: Compile the code and you'll see, that `Base10` was missing. Added above.

Answer (score 0):

macro to round number using significant figures
i didn't see anyone addressing the trailing zero to satisfy the sig fig requirements
so here a simple code to be able to round any number to the appropriate sig fig

```
Public Sub roundNumber()
Dim myNumber As Double
Dim mySigFig As Integer
Dim myRoundedNumber As Double
    
myNumber = InputBox("enter a number to round: ")
mySigFig = InputBox("enter the desired number significant figures to round: ")

myRoundedNumber = roundSigFig(myNumber, mySigFig)
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Cells(1, 1) = myRoundedNumber
    .Cells(1, 2) = myRoundedNumber
    .Cells(1, 2).NumberFormat = adjustSigFig(myRoundedNumber, mySigFig)
End With
End Sub
```

'Typical rounding scheme using significant figures

```
Public Function roundSigFig(number As Double, sigFig As Integer)
Dim power As Double

power = sigFig - Int(Log(number) / Log(10)) - 1
roundSigFig = Round(number, power)
End Function
```

'add missing 0 after rounding with sig figs

```
Public Function adjustSigFig(nb As Double, sig As Integer) As String

Dim s_nb As String  'convert number to string
Dim i As Integer
Dim len_b As Integer
Dim digit As String
Dim dot_pos As Integer
Dim dot_exist As Boolean
Dim format_zero As String
Dim extra_zero As Integer
Dim right_nb As String
Dim left_nb As String
Dim left_sig As Integer
Dim sigFig_front As Integer
Dim back_digit As Integer
Dim leading_zero As Integer
Dim trail_zero As String

'cast myNumber to string
s_nb = CStr(nb)

'count the number of characters of myNumber
len_b = Len(s_nb)

'initialize the comma position to 0
dot_pos = 0

'search if comma is present
dot_pos = InStr(1, s_nb, ".")

If dot_pos <> 0 Then
    dot_exist = True
Else
    dot_exist = False
End If

format_zero = "0."

'sig fig for integers only
If dot_exist = False Then
    'number of zero that need to be added
    If sig > len_b Then
        extra_zero = sig - len_b
        For i = 1 To extra_zero
            format_zero = format_zero & "0"
        Next i
        
        adjustSigFig = format_zero
    Else
        adjustSigFig = "0"
    End If
 Else
    

    'in this section we are looking at any string of length >2 with a comma

    'extract the left handside of the dot
    left_nb = Left(s_nb, (dot_pos - 1))
    leading_zero = 0
    
   'Initialize the trailing zero variable
    trail_zero = "0."
    
    'for any number > 0 on the left hand side of the dot
    If CInt(left_nb) > 0 Then
        'count the number of sig fig on the left of the dot
        sigFig_front = Len(left_nb)
       
        'count the number of sig fig on the right of the dot
        back_digit = Len(Right(s_nb, (Len(s_nb) - dot_pos)))
        
        'calculate the number of trailing zero needed
        left_sig = sig - (sigFig_front + back_digit)
        
        
        If left_sig > 0 Then
            For i = 1 To (back_digit + left_sig)
                trail_zero = trail_zero & "0"
            Next i

            adjustSigFig = trail_zero
        End If
        
        
        
    Else
        sigFig_front = 0
        'extract the right handside of the dotG
        right_nb = Right(s_nb, (Len(s_nb) - dot_pos))
        
    
        'check the leading 0
        For i = 1 To Len(right_nb)
            If Mid(right_nb, i, 1) = 0 Then
                leading_zero = leading_zero + 1
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i

        left_sig = Len(right_nb) - leading_zero
        trail_zero = "0."
        'compare left_sig with sig
        If sig > left_sig Then
            'then add zero
           
            For i = 1 To Len(right_nb) + (sig - (Len(right_nb) - leading_zero))
                trail_zero = trail_zero & "0"
            Next i
        
            adjustSigFig = trail_zero
        End If
    End If
End If
End Function
```